# Counting Number of Months between Two Dates in Excel

Tags: excel, date, formula, counting

So I am attempting to simply count the number of months bewtween an earlier date and today, which will be in the B:B column; once the number of months have been counted, the result is then multiplied by 28, then added back to the original date. Note the requirement: **Result >= Today**, so basically if the result is less than today it needs to add another 28 days. The current formula I made only works if the dates are in the current year (and I am not 100% sure if this formula works, it appears to so far though.)

Here is my defunct formula, but maybe someone can get a general idea from my above comments and the below formula of what I am attempting to achieve here:

`=IF(B89="","",IF(I89="X","LEG",IFERROR(IF((MONTH(TODAY()-B89)*28)+B89<TODAY(),(MONTH(TODAY()-B89)*28)+B89+28,(MONTH(TODAY()-B89)*28)+B89),"Future")))`

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Note: I just want to point out that the reference to I89 is insignificant in the above. I just didn't want to remove it in case I deleted the wrong parenthesis or some other typo, so I decided to leave in there. So basically you would not need to necessarily worry about the first two "IF" statements, nor the IFERROR, unless you just wanted to!

2ND EDIT: Okay I decided to strip down formula, original post's formula is above, the stripped version below:

`IF((MONTH(TODAY()-B89)*28)+B89<TODAY(),(MONTH(TODAY()-B89)*28)+B89+28,(MONTH(TODAY()-B89)*28)+B89)`

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and expected results?  It's unclear what specifically you're looking for

Comment: This might help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/214134

Comment: If B1's date was 1/1/16, the formula should calculate the date of 05/20/16 (otherwise the 4/20/16 would have been in the past). I am wanting these accounts reviewed every 4 weeks (which is why the number of elapsed months are multiplied by 28). However, if B1's date was 1/8/16, it would actually calculate the date to be 4-29-16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `MONTH()` for this purpose as this will lead to wrong results in some cases, and certainly when the `B89` date is in another year.

Instead see how many days you are past the last multiple of 28 days since `B89`, and go back to that date (by subtracting), and then add another 28 to it:

```
=TODAY() + 28 - MOD((TODAY()-B89), 28)
```

The earliest date this can give is the date of tomorrow. If today should be an acceptable outcome of the formula, then replace `TODAY()` with `TODAY()-1`, which results in this formula:

```
=TODAY() + 27 - MOD((TODAY()-1-B89), 28)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
=IF(B89="","",IF(I89="X","LEG",IF(IF(B89<=TODAY(),B89+28*IF(AND(B89<TODAY(),TEXT(B89,"mmyy")=TEXT(TODAY(),"mmyy")),"1",(TEXT(TODAY(),"yy")*12+MONTH(TODAY()))-(TEXT(B89,"yy")*12+MONTH(B89))),"Future")<TODAY(),TODAY(),IF(B89<=TODAY(),B89+28*IF(AND(B89<TODAY(),TEXT(B89,"mmyy")=TEXT(TODAY(),"mmyy")),"1",(TEXT(TODAY(),"yy")*12+MONTH(TODAY()))-(TEXT(B89,"yy")*12+MONTH(B89)))))))
```

Got a little long now, but you have a lot of criteria :)

Comment: The end result would have to be equal to or greater than today's date, in multiples of 28. So if 3 months have gone by since the initial date, it would have to take the three months and multiply by 28 (=84), then add the 84 days to the original date. It would need to round up as well, so if that result was before today it would need to add yet another 28 days (4 weeks).

Comment: I have amended my formula above to your criteria. Now for every month you go back it will add an additional 28 days to the date in cell B89.

Comment: sorry, missed the criteria for the same month. Fixed now.

Comment: Hmm better, but I have a start date of 4/2/15, but the formula is calculating 3/3/16. It should actually be showing today's date of 4/28/16.

Comment: So you want today's date to show if the monthly calculation comes up to a date less then today?

Comment: Just updated the formula again, I think it should do the job now.