# Is there an Excel formula that will return the number of Calendar months in a time range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need an Excel formula that will tell me the number of calendar months present in a time range.

For example:

Cell A1 Value = 5/12/2019

Cell B1 Value = 6/3/2019

Formula returns value = 2

May + June

'

Another Example:

Cell A1 Value = 3/12/2019

Cell B1 Value = 6/27/2019

Formula returns value = 4

March + April + May + June

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a replacement for web searches
and tutorials. We can help you with specific problems with your code, but we
don't re-type tutorials or write the code for you. Please see [ask]. Do some
research, then [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]. What is
the problem with it? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to
happen instead? Any errors? Good luck!

Comment: Hey!  Is my question not specific enough?  I looked on the website and couldn't find a similar question.  I need this for an interest rate calculation

Comment: @oryan5000 usually it is expected that one would also show what one has tried and what is not working with that approach.  But as this was a fairly simple formula, I answered.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I will be better about this in future questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting Number of Months between Two Dates in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917334/counting-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MONTH() and YEAR()

```
=MONTH(B1)-MONTH(A1)+1+(YEAR(B1)-YEAR(A1))*12
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott, I really appreciate it!  You're going to make me look smart at my new job so I appreciate it